# Programming Language Design Paridigms or Signals and Systems

Tags: design-patterns, signals

Not really a programming question, but I am suppose to pick a module selection for my next year university course. However, I am unable to understand what these 2 courses are about and which of this course is more suitable for me. Is there anyone that is able to summarise these 2 modules and tell me what to expect for these modules? Much thanks.

Comment: About _Signals and Systems_: it seems to be a [systems theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_theory) (related) module. In... very short: everything in this world is a system. The systems theory puts the theoretical tools at disposal, with which a system of any kind can be modeled/designed/analysed. In systems theory, any system can be abstracted as a big box. In the box is injected a signal (input). From the box comes out a signal (output).

Comment: Now, the big box can have other boxes (e.g. subsystems) inside. Each has input and output signals too. The in/out signals can be of a multitude of types. An output signal of a (sub)system can be the input signal for another. And so on... The systems theory applied in electronics is fun.